# Sending multiple email with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

I'm using Codeigniter 2 for my website. When send email to multiple users , on  client( gmail, hotmail,..) it shows all addresse on details , how can i hide the addresses to show just the receiver address.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use bcc to send batch emails like this:

```
function batch_email($recipients, $subject, $message) 
{
  $this->email->clear(TRUE);
  $this->email->from('you@yoursite.com', 'Display Name'); 
  $this->email->to('youremailaddress@yourserver.com');
  $this->email->bcc($recipients);
  $this->email->subject($subject);
  $this->email->message($message);  

  $this->email->send();

    return TRUE;

}
```

$recipients should be a comma-delimited list or an array

It means that you will get a copy of the email but all other recipients will be bcc'ed, so won't see each other's addresses

Comment: I don't always answer questions, but when I do, the user who posted it doesn't come back to tell me if helped :-(

Comment: thanks @whisperson Sir!.. this save me a time... and works like charm!

Comment: I wish I could find a good, comprehensive tutorial on codeigniter bcc. I just can't seem to get the bcc to work, and I have tried comma delimitted lists and arrays.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are assigning all recipients in a single **to** method, like

```
$this->email->to('one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com');
```

This will mail to all recipients at once. To prevent showing all recipients, mail it separately for each user, as follows,

```
foreach ($list as $name => $address)
{
    $this->email->clear();
    $this->email->to($address);
    $this->email->from('your@example.com');
    $this->email->subject('Here is your info '.$name);
    $this->email->message('Hi '.$name.' Here is the info you requested.');
    $this->email->send();
}
```

Here `$list` contains array of Recipient name and email ID. Make sure to use `clear()` at the beginning of each iteration.

Comment: Seems like you shouldn't have to send separate emails to each recipient, when that's what the bcc is supposed to do.